# Using ipopt within Pyomo, how can I query whether the current solution is feasible?

Tags: python, pyomo, nonlinear-optimization, ipopt

I have an ipopt model that sometimes suffers from small numerical issues. I have a correction algorithm that can fix them, but may cause small violations of other inequalities. I need a way to determine whether the current solution is feasible without manually querying each variable bound and constraint. How can I do this within pyomo?

I know there's a way to log infeasible constraints to standard output, but this does not help me. I need my code to react dynamically to these infeasibilities, such as running a few more iterations post-correction.

More info:
I have a (relatively) small but highly nonlinear problem modeled in Pyomo. The model sometimes suffers from numerical issues with ipopt when certain variables are near zero. (I'm modeling unit vectors from full vectors via max*uvec=vec with some magnitude constraint, which becomes really messy when the magnitude of a vector is near-zero.) Fortunately, it is possible to compute everything in the model from a few key driving variables, so that small numerical infeasibilities in definition-type constraints (e.g. defining unit vectors) are easily resolved, but such resolution may cause small violations of the main problem constraints.

Some things I've tried:

1. The log_infeasible_constraints function from from pyomo.util.infeasible: only prints to standard output, and I cannot find any documentation on the function (to see if there are flags allowing it to be used for my needs). (The function returns None, so I can't e.g. simply check return string length.)

Update: I found the source code at https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/pyomo/util/infeasible.py, which could be salvaged to create a (clunky) solution. However, I suspect this could still miss some things (e.g. other tolerance criteria) that could cause ipopt to consider a solution infeasible.

2. is_feasible = (results.solver.status == SolverStatus.ok) #(where opt=SolverFactory('ipopt'), and  results=opt.solve(model))
   This only works immediately after the solve. If the solver runs out of iterations or variables are changed post-solve, this gives no indication of current model feasibility.

(Currently, I blindly run the correction step after each solve since I can't query model feasibility.)

Comment: I often use different NLP solvers to solve a single problem. IPOPT is good at getting close to the solution, but an active set solver may produce more polished solutions. In that case, it may make sense to first solve with IPOPT and then restart with an active set algorithm such as CONOPT or SNOPT.